# Python 3 Index Error list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy entrenando una red neuronal para reconocer imagenes, trate de correr mi codigo en Colabororatory de Google pues mi computadora tarde demasiado en correrlo, aqui va mi codigo

```
dirname = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'sportimages')
imgpath = dirname + os.sep 

images = []
directories = []
dircount = []
prevRoot=''
cant=0

print("leyendo imagenes de ",imgpath)

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(imgpath):
for filename in filenames:
    if re.search("\.(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|tiff)$", filename):
        cant=cant+1
        filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
        image = plt.imread(filepath)
        images.append(image)
        b = "Leyendo..." + str(cant)
        print (b, end="\r")
        if prevRoot !=root:
            print(root, cant)
            prevRoot=root
            directories.append(root)
            dircount.append(cant)
            cant=0
dircount.append(cant)
```

Y aqui es donde empieza el problema

```
dircount = dircount[1:]
dircount[0]=dircount[0]+1
```

segun parece el error este en la linea de arriba.
El error que me marca es el siguiente:

```
 IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-6-2875b978f7c4> in <module>()
  18 
  19 dircount = dircount[1:]
 --->  20 dircount[0]=dircount[0]+ 1
  21 print('Directorios leidos:',len(directories))
  22 print("Imagenes en cada directorio", dircount)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

¿Alguien podría indicarme donde esta el error?
Corri el mismo programa en jupyter y corrio sin problemas (salvo por el error de memoria cuando trato de convertir mis datos a categoricos, pero ese es otro problema)

Comment: Hola Adrian  el error indica que `dircount` es una lista vacía.

Comment: Cuando llegas al último elemento de tu lista, digase elemento n, tú intentas acceder al elmeneto n+1 en la línea 20, por lo que python truena, ya que estás accediendo a un espacio que no existe en esa lista, tendrías que validar ese caso específico, y tambíén valida la lista que usas, que no venga vacía.

Saludos!

Comment: pudiste solucionar? Ayuda tengo el mismo error